Regex with start and end that could be different
I am trying to search and replace in VS code thousands of instances, etc.
Sample String:
[[123|123]] and [[4567|4567]], also [[89|89]].

Finding \[\[.*\|(.*)\]\] and replacing with [[$1]]. It finds [[123|123]] and [[4567|4567]], also [[89|89]]turns the whole string into [[123]].. The values inside the brackets could be any length of characters, but the pipe does separate them.
I tried anchoring start and end with ^\[\[.*\|(.*)\]\]$, but then nothing matched.
Wanted result:
[[123]] and [[456]], also [[789]].


try \[\[([^]|]*)\|\1\]\] replace with [[$1]]

If you want to find anything in between the brackets ([[ ]]), you need to filter for any character, which is not ] instead of any character (.).
If not it will select the whole string.
[^t]* = is every character except t
[^\]]* = is every character except ]
So try \[\[[^\]]*\]\] as regex
Even if this does not solve your problem fully, it hopefully will give you the idea.

I found the answer, but I don't know why it works. I was just continuing to play and found that this works for the search:
\[\[.*?\|(.*?)\]\]


The examples in your question are all about a duplicated number, like [[a|a]], where we have a appearing twice. The regex you supply here would also match [[a|b]], where the two numbers are different. Is that intentional? If so, the question is misleading.

adding ? to * or + makes them non greedy
